# Mediawiki, can't login after password change

Tags: php, mysql, mediawiki

I'm using MediaWiki 1.27.0 on Ubuntu 14.04

I haven't set up email on the server yet, so I was going to reset a users password using the `maintenance/changePassword.php` script that mediawiki provides.

When I ran their command

```
php maintenance/changePassword.php --conf=/var/www/html/LocalSettings.php --user=myuser --password=newPassword
```

It said `Password set for myuser`

Now no one can log in, and everyone gets the same error of

**There seems to be a problem with your login session; this action has been canceled as a precaution against session hijacking. Go back to the previous page, reload that page and then try again.**

I'm at a loss as to how to fix this.  I find other's who have had this error with an older version of mediawiki, and the next version of mediawiki seems to have fixed their problem.  But obviously, that can't fix this issue.

Any help is appreciated.

---

**What I've tried**

I looked through the user accounts in the database to make sure their change password script hadn't done anything odd, and it all looks fine.

I tried [this crazy solution](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Pjby0sdeg3e60rfy) that said you should create a tmp directory in the root of mediawiki and give it 777 access.  I tried that, just for giggles, then deleted the directory.

Comment: The first thing to check on session errors is whether the session works (does your server set a session cookie? does your browser send it back?). The second is to check the `session` and `authentication` log channels which might give you a hint of where things go wrong.

Comment: FWIW the error message you are quoting is shown when the CSRF tokens do not match. When you open the login form, the server saves a random token to the session and also put it in the login form as a hidden field. Matching the token that's submitted with the form against the token in the session will prove that you are you and protect against [cross-site request forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attacks. If that does not work, either the server cannot write to the session (e.g. `$wgSessionCacheType` is something non-useful) or setting the session cookie fails.

Comment: Thank you for the help @Tgr.  I don't actually have the ```$wgSessionCacheType``` variable in my LocalSettings.php.  How do I check the ```session``` and ```authentication``` log channels?

Comment: Right now I can restart apache, and it resets everything temporarily.  Which makes it sound like you're correct to me.

Comment: You can use some debugging tool ([`eval.php`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Eval.php), PsySh, XDebug...) to check  `$wgSessionCacheType`, or you can use something like `\MediaWiki\Session\SessionManager::singleton()->getSessionById( str_repeat( '0', 32), true )->set( 'foo', 1 );` (on a different request) `\MediaWiki\Session\SessionManager::singleton()->getSessionById( str_repeat( '0', 32) )->get( 'foo' )` to verify that the backend session data store itself is persisted accross requests.

Comment: See [Creating custom log groups](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug#Creating_custom_log_groups) about logging specific channels (or groups, it's the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

This isn't the solution.  After restarting apache2, I was able to login, but the same problem happened again.  I'm not sure what happened yet, but this definitely didn't resolve the problem more than just temporarily.

---

I was going to delete this question, but I think it's only a matter of time before it actually helps some noob like me.

The instructions on manually resetting the mediawiki passwords without email don't say that you should restart apache once you have run the script, but this seems to be required. That should have been my first step, but I started freaking out, and everything I knew to do went straight out the window.

So, if you manually reset passwords on mediawiki, and you get this error, restart apache.  Actually, if you ever get an error for any reason....this is probably a good thing to try anyway.

Comment: It should not be required. Maybe you changed some configuration setting earlier and forgot to restart/reload Apache.