# Mediawiki login cancelled to prevent session hijacking

Tags: php, session, mediawiki

I have just set up a MediaWiki 1.29.0 page on an AS400 IBM i machine. I am using MariaDB as a database. I am using PHP 5.5.37

Every time I try to log into an account, I get the error:

> There seems to be a problem with your login session; this action has been canceled as a precaution against session hijacking. Go back to the previous page, reload that page and then try again.

Obviously, the behavior I'm looking for is to log in.

I've tried:

- changing `$wgMainCacheType` and `$wgSessionCacheType` to various permutations of `CACHE_NONE`, `CACHE_ACCEL`, `CACHE_DB`, and `CACHE_ANYTHING`.
- [creating a tmp directory](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Pjby0sdeg3e60rfy) and setting its permissions.
- rebuilding my `LocalSettings.php` file.
- setting `session.referer_check=off` in php.ini

I've checked and I know my cookies are enabled (I'm able to call `document.cookie;` and get data back).

This question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812604/cant-log-in-to-mediawiki-canceled-as-a-precaution-against-session-hijacking?noredirect=1&lq=1), and the linked questions within, but no solutions fixed my problem. They also deal with an older version of WikiMedia, though I don't know if that makes a difference in this instance.

EDIT: I am also getting the same behavior when I try to create a new account. However, I am able to navigate the wiki, create pages, and edit pages without any sort of error.

Here is my request header:

```
Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Connection: close
Content-language: en
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 10 Aug 2017 13:48:36 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Link: </<path>/resources/assets/logo.png?88d75>;rel=preload;as=image
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: ZDEDebuggerPresent=php,phtml,php3; path=/
Set-Cookie: <wikiname>_session=n7gs0ct99ck5i2juq0togto9q7bfou6u; path=/; secure; httponly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding,Cookie
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.37 ZendServer/8.5.5
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
```

Here is my response header:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:ZDEDebuggerPresent=php,phtml,php3
Host:tdidev:10080
Referer:http://<wikiepath>/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&retirnto=Main+Page
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of the `authentication`, `login`, `session`, `caches` and `objectcache` [log channels](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgDebugLogGroups) and the HTTP request and response headers when you try to log in?

Comment: Is this the request where you submit the login form? If so, it's missing the login cookie. So either MediaWiki did not set it for some reason (check for a `Set-Cookie` header in the previous request, where the login page was initially displayed), or the browser did not preserve it for some reason ([T151770](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T151770) is a known issue with Firefox that can result in that).

Comment: Uh, sorry, I meant check for `Set-Cookie` in the response where the login page gets displayed to you. So it should look something like this: `GET Special:UserLogin` --> `HTTP 200 Set-Cookie: SomeWiki_session: xxxxx` --> `POST Special:UserLogin Cookie: SomeWiki_session: xxxxx` -> `HTTP 302 Set-Cookie: SomeWiki_user: xxx Location: Main_Page`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've finally found the issue to my problem. By default, MediaWiki passes the `<wikiname>_session` cookie with the secure flag set. Taken from [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag):

> The secure flag is an option that can be set by the application server when sending a new cookie to the user within an HTTP Response. The purpose of the secure flag is to prevent cookies from being observed by unauthorized parties due to the transmission of a the cookie in clear text.
>
> To accomplish this goal, browsers which support the secure flag will only send cookies with the secure flag when the request is going to a HTTPS page. Said in another way, the browser will not send a cookie with the secure flag set over an unencrypted HTTP request.

So my MediaWiki installation correctly creates and caches a session token, and it even still passes it through the response header. However, since my browser sees an `http` instead of `https`, that's as far as the token gets. The `Set-Cookie` line is simply ignored.

There is a setting in php.ini called `session.cookie_secure`, but MediaWiki ignores this flag.

Instead, the solution was to add this line to the bottom of my `localSettings.php` file:

`$wgCookieSecure = false;`

Answer (score 3):

I had something similar happen on a different application, when the sessionId was being updated out of sequence.

So normally you request a login form, and it creates a session with a sessionId, and stores this somewhere.

Then you submit the form, it ties that into the original sessionId, checks your authentication, and either logs in the original session, or creates you a new one, and updates yours (normally with a HTTP `Set-Cookie` command you can see in the Network log).

But you can follow everything, by looking at the sessionId in your current cookies, and any token on the form (to prevent replays), and checking it against either your /tmp/php-session-xxx file (maybe in /var/lib/php) or whatever database it's storing the session in.

What tipped me off to my problem was identifing that by the time I was about to submit a form, with a particular sessionid, that sessionid, was no-longer valid.  Hence I failed the replay checks, and I got an error similar to yours.  It turned out in my case it was to do with the databases replicating in a way that didn't match how they were being accessed downstream so I could attempt to access a session, that hadn't been created yet.

Looking at all your code, the sessionIds don't match.  `wpTokenLogin` starts with `510a85` but your wiki session in `SetCookie` starts with `n7gs0c` and in your log it talks about `6ov933`...  So assuming you copied/pasted from different attempts, you need to run through it yourself from a clean state and check that everything looks like it's using the same session.  If not, try to figure out what's happening to the session you have (if it's created/changed) or why you're not getting the right one, if it's created but never passed out to you properly.

That said, I just took at look at the client side of logging into our own inhouse version of mediawiki, and `wpLoginToken`, `wikidb_session` and `JSESSIONID` don't match either (although I'd expect one of them to show up in the wiki log, which I don't have access too).

If you have to, grep the source for the error message you're finding, and insert `error_log(__FILE__.':'.__LINE__.' '.var_export(debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS), true));` to find out work back up the stack, to see what didn't match, to generate the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ongoing problem with MediaWiki, and is the result of your password being incorrectly entered, or MediaWiki failed to write **SOMETHING** during the login process (database, cookie, disk file, whatever). In my case, I was using the $wgReadOnly variable to make the wiki read-only. I found that I had to use $wgMainCacheType = CACHE_MEMCACHED for my system to work properly.

See: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Memcached